# does pytest-catchlog support logging to multiple files

Tags: python, logging, pytest

pytest.ini looks like this:

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = CRITICAL
log_cli_format = %(message)s

log_file = debug.log
log_file_level = DEBUG
log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_file_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

is there way I can specify what file to log into based on log_file_level? I want to have multiple logs (debug.log, info.log, error.log etc) and each of these files will contain logs with the specified log level or higher

so something like this

```
[pytest]
log_cli = 1
log_cli_level = CRITICAL
log_cli_format = %(message)s

log_file = debug.log
log_file_level = DEBUG
log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_file_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S

log_file = info.log
log_file_level = INFO
log_file_format = %(asctime)s [%(levelname)8s] %(message)s (%(filename)s:%(lineno)s)
log_file_date_format=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

however this does not work since cannot have duplicate names in pytest.ini

another plugin I tried was pytest-logger, but I don't like it very much

Comment: This is currently not possible, unfortunately.